# Find a word in current file

Tags: emacs

Normally when I code, I use Visual studio, Notepad++, and Eclipse. To find a word there, I'd just press ctrl+F. Then I can use the "Enter" key to jump through the matched words.

It is the same I want to do in Emacs.
For example, I want to find the words with name (or containing) dateID.

I am pretty new to Emacs, and I'm having difficulties in finding a way to find a word/text. Maybe I'm searching on wrong things, but searching here and on google comes up with everything, except what I need. I searched on different words, like "Search for text emacs" among others.

Comment: `C-s` and start typing. `C-s` again for next match. `C-r` for prev match. `f1 t` for tutorial.

Comment: Also `M-C-s` for `isearch-forward-regex`.

Comment: @tripleee, OP was using notepad++, don't scare him with regexes, jeez:)

Comment: Do you allow to introduce `Alt-x occur` ? :D I'll stop here.

Comment: Also `C-h t` for the tutorial, and http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/index.html if you really don't have the manual installed locally.  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Search.html#Search is the chapter on search.

Comment: +1 for @tripleeee's comment.  Get to know the Emacs manual and Emacs help commands/keys, so you can ***ask Emacs first***.  You will not regret that habit.

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't know what `C-s` means.(Sorry if you know, but I'm serious.)

- `C` in `C-s` means `Control key`.
- `-` in `C-s` means `And`.
- `s` in `C-s` means just "s" key.

So `C-s` means `Down control key and then "s" key and then up both key`.

Now you executed `isearch-forward` command that is bound to `C-s`. And you can quit this command by pressing `C-g`.

In ordinary editor `C-f` is bound something like "find string on this file" but in Emacs `C-f` is bound to `forward-char`. So Emacs keybinding is completely different from other ordinary editor(like notepad.exe msword.exe on windows).